# SQL: Get data by date and range of a column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called 'Library' below with three columns. I need to get count of range of dwell_time for each date. The ranges I need is 0-30 , 31-60, 61-90 and 91-100.

```
    Id   Date        dwell_time 
    1  2015-05-10      27
    2  2015-05-10      28
    3  2015-05-10      32
    4  2015-05-10      65
    5  2015-05-11      27
    6  2015-05-11      28
    7  2015-05-11      65
```

should return

```
2015-05-10 0-30 2
2015-05-10 31-60 1
2015-05-10 61-90 1
2015-05-11 0-30 2
2015-05-11 61-90 1
```

Can you please help with the query I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    date,
    date_range,
    count(1)
FROM (
    SELECT
        date,
        CASE
            WHEN dwell_time BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '0-30'
            WHEN dwell_time BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN '31-60'
            WHEN dwell_time BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '61-90'
            ELSE '90-100'
        END AS date_range
    FROM Library) lib
GROUP BY date, date_range
```

EDIT (by Gordon, because I was asked in the comments):

```
    SELECT date,
           (CASE WHEN dwell_time BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '0-30'
                 WHEN dwell_time BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN '31-60'
                 WHEN dwell_time BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '61-90'
                 ELSE '90-100'
            END) AS date_range,
           COUNT(*)
    FROM Library l
    GROUP BY date, date_range
    ORDER BY date, date_range;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f7bd/15) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: You don't need the subquery for this query.

Comment: Vadim - Thanks it worked. @Gordon Linoff: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can put the `CASE` directly in the `GROUP BY`. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f7bd/11. I think this answer is more readable though.

Comment: if I had to use WHERE clause along with this how do I that ? Considering I had another column 'Campus' and I wanted it to get values only for particular campus lets say WHERE Campus = 'UMCP'. How do I do that?